# javascript syntax for new objects and prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'm femiliar with OOP from PHP / JAVA but i'm a newbie in JS prototype objects.

My question is: I found that there are 4 ways (probably more) to instantiate a new object:

```
1. var d = Object.create(Object.prototype);
2. var d = {};
3. var d = new Object();
4. 
var d = function(){};
d.prototype = {a:xxx, b:yyy};
```

what is the different between the four in regards to the prototype (as i understand prototype is the main Object constructor which all object inherits from).

Hope I got it right....thanks,
Danny

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are all equivalent (all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`). 4 is different since `d` is not an object like the others, it's a *constructor function*. you can use the function to *create* a new object, which will then inherit from `d.prototype`. You should have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects).

Comment: why not post this as an answer...i can't accept it :( but it helped alot :)

Comment: @FelixKling is there any other way to create an object constructor?

Comment: It's all explained in the article I linked to. There are no other ways as those mentioned there.